# Why function call only pass the first argument

Tags: c, call

I'm trying to call a function (on line 15) just via a cast but only the first argument is getting passed, how could I fix it?

I tried to change the float value "2" to 2.0f to declare it's a float and not an int but it's still not working.

!Note that the code is horrible because it's a [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), the line 15 has to be in a dll form later, this code here is just a test program to avoid launching the target process multiples times. Here's my actual code with a score of 58 chars

```c
DllMain(a,b,c){((int(*)(int,float))927309216)(‭7903472‬,2);}
```

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char * sSkelModelStencil = "SkelModelStencil"; //here I reproduce the char like it is in the memory

void SetConsoleFloat(const char *sKey, float fVal) //this is the reproduction of SetConsoleFloat in CShell.dll
{
    printf("arg1:    %s    arg2: %f\n", sKey, fVal); //printing the arguments getting passed into the function
    return;
}

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        SetConsoleFloat("SkelModelStencil", 2); //calling the reproduction function
        ((int(*)())SetConsoleFloat)(sSkelModelStencil,2); //calling the reproduction function via a cast & using SetConsoleFloat addr
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the 15 line contains weird cast because it's a code golf and I can't put too much characters.

Comment: This screams undefined behaviour, so it's hard to say for sure, but I'd put my money on the called function expecting the `float` to be in a XMM register (assuming x86-64) and your cast not including the argument list, and the caller thus not putting it there.

Comment: If you have to keep it short, why do you need the cast at all?

Comment: it has to be in a dll form, here's my actual code with a score of 58
```DllMain(a,b,c){((int(*)(int,float))927309216)(‭7903472‬,2);}```

Comment: @ChrisHoffmann You should put your comment into the question.

Answer (score 2):

In some architectures, the way arguments are passed depends on the way they're declared. For instance, special registers may be used for `float` parameters. It's the declaration of the function type that matters, not the declaration of the argument expression.

The parameter signature `()` is different from `(const char *sKey, float fVal)`, and as a result the `fVal` argument is being passed differently from the way the function expects to receive it.

Comment: tl;dr Change `((int(*)())SetConsoleFloat)` to `((void(*)(const char*, float))SetConsoleFloat)` and watch it magically work. ;-)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar He said he has to use the short cast for code golf reasons. I'm not sure why he needs a cast at all, though.

Comment: I can do this but sadly, it's a code golf challenge and I have to save characters, but thanks you! My code has to be in a dll form and injected into a process, then it has to call a function.

Comment: @ChrisHoffmann : You won't get the call right without using the proper argument list unless you explore your compiler and find out which sequence of calls preceding it (or anything else, really) cause the compiler to leave the value you want in the register that the called function needs. Perhaps this is the real challenge.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - this is atrocious code, don't do that.

Secondly - compile your code with compiler warnings on, so the compiler can tell you where you might be going wrong. Of course, you need a proper C compiler (which MSVC is not, in case you were using that). gcc will tell you:

```
a.c:15:10: warning: function called through a non-compatible type
```

But, to answer your question: You're casting into the wrong type of function: You're using the function type `void ()`; but you need `void (const char*, float)`. So, try:

```
((void(*)(const char*, float))SetConsoleFloat)(sSkelModelStencil,2);
```

instead of your existing line 15. It's also a good idea to separate casts from type definitions of functions - for clarity - so you would have:

```
typedef  void (*scf_function_t)(const char*, float);
```

earlier, and then:

```
((scf_function_t) SetConsoleFloat)(sSkelModelStencil,2);
```

but again - there's really no good reason to do any of this in the first place.

Comment: It's a code golf challenge, of course it's attrocious code.

Comment: It's judged on brevity, not clarity.

Comment: @Barmar: Ah, sorry, I mistook you for OP. Rephrashing: Most people who will find this question here on the site will not know what OP's intention was as the author, and won't be familiar with the term "code golf" either. We need to consider the wider audience when answering questions. It is important to tell people not to write this kind of code.

Comment: I've added a link to what code golf is to his question.